# LibreOffice Calc crash

Tags: libreoffice, crash

LibreOffice Calc has been crashing a lot since yesterday.  Is there a bug in a recent update?  Will it be fixed?

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LibreOffice 6.4.7.2

Comment: any log files or crash reports? without that nobody can really help (not us, not the developers)

Comment: Where would I find log files or crash reports?  Are they stored somewhere?  I'm not a real techie, just a user.

Comment: [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/lo/text/shared/guide/error_report.html) is information about sending a crash report to the developers. If you want you can try running LibreOffice from terminal (`libreoffice --calc <filename>`) and then post output here so we can (maybe) see what's happening

Comment: you can also go to `/var/crash` and look for a crash report from libreoffice

Comment: I tried to paste it in but it's too long.  For the command in terminal, what should I enter for <filename> ? I get an error message whether I put in SONGSANDSOURCES.xls or just SONGSANDSOURCES.  That is the name of my spreadsheet I was working on.  bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: what kind of error? it should work. regardless you can do `libreoffice --calc` and then open files afterwards. EDIT: I assume you left out the `<>` in the actual command, but if you didn't then do that.

Comment: Ahhh, okay, yeah, I just edited my last comment but here it is again:   bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: check my comment's edit: that's probably because you left the `<>`. They are just a placeholder, so you should use `libreoffice --calc SONGSANDSOURCES.xls` (no angled brackets in the final command).

Comment: I'm being asked to move this to chat.  If I say yes, will I automatically connect to you?

Comment: Also, I did run it without the <> and got an error:  javaldx: could not find a JavaRuntime environment!
Please ensure that a JVM and the package libreoffice-java-common is installed.
If it is already installed then try removing (squiggly character) /.config/libreoffice/4/user/config
warning: failed to read path from javadlx

Comment: perhaps that's the problem, LibreOffice relies on Java for some functionality.  You can try `java -version` to see if you have Java installed, and `sudo apt install libreoffice-java-common` to install that/check if it is installed. Which changes did you make recently (apt updates, other updates, installing/removing software, etc)?

Comment: I haven't made any changes manually, only the updates that come through automatically through the software updates.  And there have been a lot of them in the last couple of weeks.  In fact, there's one waiting for me now.  I'll check on the java but right now I have to leave my desk for a bit.  Just to let you know so you won't keep waiting on me.  I'll come back later if your latest advice doesn't work.  Basically all I wanted to know was whether I'm the only one experiencing this and is somebody on it.

Comment: This question is simply unanswerable without additional information from your logs or crash reports.

Comment: Sorry, I've been tied up with some other things and I'll have to set this aside for now.